# Comparing 'mobile numbers' - and/or international format

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-3.5

I am receiving phone numbers from a mobile device, format varies from international format or not.

**Scenario  (ZA formats just for the example) :**

Registered numbers in database are always international format : +27827177982

Numbers I receive can vary e.g. `+27827177982` = `27827177982` = `0827177982` - international prefix for number is `+27`

How do I match it to the international format even though I don't receive the international format???

---

**Keep in mind :**

I can't do conversion just for 1 region.

Is there a simple way of comparing mobile phone numbers for all regions?

Prefixes ranges in amount of chars reference : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes

---

**My ideas :**

- Compare the last 9 characters of the number, this will rule out the region prefix... but does every region only have '9 characters excluding the prefix'?
- Loop through the database comparing the phone numbers a couple a times e.g. check for last 9 numbers - if no match - check for last 10 etc. (But can cause unwanted matches)

---

**Any help would greatly be appreciated**

Comment: Knowing the country of origin of at least ONE phone number (assuming you are always comparing two), is very helpful here...Then you can build a solid algorithm...I have done this a few times, let me know if you still want assistance :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to look into using a library for this. For example, Google's [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) library with a C# [port being here](https://bitbucket.org/pmezard/libphonenumber-csharp/wiki/Home). In particular, these two methods may be worth looking into (emphasis mine)

> **isNumberMatch** - gets a confidence level on whether two numbers could
>   be the same.
>
> **getExampleNumber/getExampleNumberByType** - provides valid
>   example numbers for all countries/regions, with the option of
>   specifying which type of example phone number is needed.

Comment: Looks very promising! Thanks! I will give it a shot and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

In most countries (the US being a notable exception), non-international numbers start with a 0, so the solution will be something like:

- If the country is on a list of exceptions, deal with it specially.
- otherwise

  - If first character is `0`, remove it and add international country code
  - Ensure first character is `+`.

There isn't any easy answer to this, because there are no internationally set rules no how phone numbers work.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this. This is written off the top of my head:

```
string sourcePhoneNumber = "....";
string phoneNumber = "....";

int baseRegionCountryCode = 44;

if (phoneNumber.StartsWith("0") && !phoneNumber.StartsWith("00"))
{
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.SubString(0, 1);
    phoneNumber = String.Format("{0}{1}", baseRegionCountryCode, phoneNumber);
}
else if (phoneNumber.StartsWith("+"))
{
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.Replace("+", "00");
}

if (sourcePhoneNumber == phoneNumber)
{
    // do something awesome....
}
```